# Javascript filter JSON by date

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement the solution to find data from JSON by date
here is the JSON data

```
[
  {
        draw_date: "2021-06-30T00:00:00.000",
        winning_numbers: "24 29 50 65 66 14",
        multiplier: "4"
    },
    {
        draw_date: "2021-06-26T00:00:00.000",
        winning_numbers: "08 31 39 43 60 17",
        multiplier: "3"
    }
];
```

I have implemented the solution

```js
const result = [
  {
        draw_date: "2021-06-30T00:00:00.000",
        winning_numbers: "24 29 50 65 66 14",
        multiplier: "4"
    },
    {
        draw_date: "2021-06-26T00:00:00.000",
        winning_numbers: "08 31 39 43 60 17",
        multiplier: "3"
    }
];
const date = result.find(data => data.draw_date == '2021-06-30T00:00:00.000')
console.log(date);
```

But the solution is only finding the data by exact date string for example

`2021-06-30T00:00:00.000`

If I search like this

`2021-06-30`

Getting `undefind`

Any idea? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `includes` as below

```js
const result = [
  {
        draw_date: "2021-06-30T00:00:00.000",
        winning_numbers: "24 29 50 65 66 14",
        multiplier: "4"
    },
    {
        draw_date: "2021-06-26T00:00:00.000",
        winning_numbers: "08 31 39 43 60 17",
        multiplier: "3"
    }
];
const date = result.find(data => data.draw_date.includes('2021-06-30'))
console.log(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `string == "2021-06-30"` in your data. The first string called `draw_date` is `2021-06-30T00:00:00.000`, which is clearly not the same string.

You will need to use an expression to match a string that starts with the searched date string.

It appears the date format is well-defined, and if you can rely on that, then perhaps `startsWith` might be helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith

Answer (score 1):

You are calling filtering on the basis of `2021-06-30T00:00:00.000`, if it matches in the array you will get a response.

For the solution you can use the below code:

```
const result = [
  {
        draw_date: "2021-06-30T00:00:00.000",
        winning_numbers: "24 29 50 65 66 14",
        multiplier: "4"
    },
    {
        draw_date: "2021-06-26T00:00:00.000",
        winning_numbers: "08 31 39 43 60 17",
        multiplier: "3"
    }
];
const date = result.find(data => data.draw_date == '2021-06-30T00:00:00.000' || data.draw_date.split("T")[0] == '2021-06-30');
```

Or

```
cost date = result.find(data => data.draw_date.split("T")[0] == '2021-06-30');
```

Output :

```
{draw_date: "2021-06-30T00:00:00.000", winning_numbers: "24 29 50 65 66 14", multiplier: "4"}
```

Alternatives :

1. You can use `includes` which can check if the string matches or not
2. We have `loadash(underscore.js)` as well to fetch and organize JSON

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between `2021-06-30T00:00:00.000` and `2021-06-30` when using the equality operator (`==`). Instead of searching, you're checking if those two values are equal, which they are not.

What you want to use is [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

```
const date = result.find(data => data.draw_date.indexOf('2021-06-30'))
console.log(date);
```